# Solving for Explicit Form (Differential Equations step)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation $(\alpha)$:
        $$I'=r\cdot I(S-I) \text{ , }\ I(0)=I_0.$$
Where $r$ is a positive constant. 
Also, we are given the fact that:
        $$ \lim_{t\to\infty} I(t)=S.$$ 
Which I later have to prove as part of the question, I can do that, once I have this part resolved.

I have arrived at the point where I have the following:
$$\frac{-I(t)}{S-I(t)}=e^{S (rt+c)}.$$

Mathematica gives me the result:
$$I(t)=\frac{S e^{S (c+r t)}}{e^{S (c+r t)}-1}.$$

However, I have no clue how to solve this manually for $I(t)$.
How would I go about doing such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have reached the point where you have

$\dfrac{-I(t)}{S-I(t)} = e^{S(rt + c)}, \tag{1}$

then arriving at the form

$I(t) = \dfrac{Se^{S(rt+ c)}}{e^{S(rt + c)} - 1} \tag{2}$

is easy, requiring only elementary algebra; indeed, from (1),

$-I(t) = e^{S(rkt + c)}(S - I(t)) = e^{S(rt + c)}S - e^{S(rt + c)} I(t), \tag{3}$

whence

$e^{S(rt + c)} I(t) - I(t) = (e^{S(rt + c)} - 1) I((t) = e^{S(rt + c)}S, \tag{4}$

whence

$I(t) = \dfrac{S e^{S(rt + c)}}{e^{S(rt + c)} - 1}, \tag{5}$

in agreement with the result reported of Mathematica.

Answer (score 3):

$\dfrac{I-S}{I} = e^{-S(rt+c)} \Rightarrow I(1-e^{-S(rt+c)}) = S \Rightarrow I = \dfrac{S}{1-\dfrac{1}{e^{S(rt+c)}}} = \dfrac{Se^{S(rt+c)}}{-1+e^{S(rt+c)}}$